# Information on the FLUENTAL ® moderator/ shifter. How and who made it?

Tags: radiology, nuclear-radiation

The FLUENTAL® moderator/shifter appears often in the literature surrounding BNCT therapy. Google offers no search results with useful information on how it was made and whom by.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I think you must have confused Fluental with something else. It has nothing to do with radiology studies or BNCT therapy.

Comment: @CareyGregory Actually I think the OP is referring to the proprietary moderator material in BNCT of the same name - it's a composite material made of Aluminium Flouride, Aluminium and Lithium Fluoride

Comment: @motosubatsu Ah, so I see from JonMark's answer.

Answer (score 4):

After looking (without result!) at loads of pages returned from a Bing search for BNCT, I hit upon searching for:

> [FLUENTAL moderator](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%20FLUENTAL%20moderator&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=fluental%20moderator&sc=0-18&sk=&cvid=AE6A53394FB447BBB8053908D0688FEC)

The first reference I looked at was:

- [Use of TEPCs for characterising BNCT Beams](http://www.npl.co.uk/upload/pdf/20061026_nuc_green_1.pdf)

but there is no reference to the manufacturer.

However, the opening chapter of:

- [Chemical aspects on the final disposal of irradiated](https://www.vtt.fi/inf/pdf/technology/2014/T156.pdf)

reads:

> The Boron Neutron Capture Therapy (BNCT) at VTT utilized the FiR 1 TRIGA reactor as a source for the neutron beam. The fast fission neutrons from the reactor needed to be slowed down to the epithermal energy range (0.5 eV–10 keV) prior to reaching the patient. The epithermal neutrons were produced in a block of FLUENTAL™ set between the the reactor and the patient. **FLUENTAL™ is a patented material that has been developed and produced by VTT (Auterinen & Salmenhaara 2008, Savolainen et al. 2013)**. The composition of FLUENTAL™ is AlF3 (69 w-%), metallic aluminium (30 w-%) and LiF (1 w-%). The manufacturing process is based on a hot isostatic pressing technique, which results in a FLUENTAL™ product consisting of solid blocks with a density of 3 000 kg/m3. The decommissioning of the FiR 1 reactor leaves VTT with two options; to sell it abroad or to dispose of it together with the other decommissioning waste. At present, both options are considered and the final decision will be made at a later stage.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Fluental](https://www.drugs.com/international/fluental.html) is a drug sold in Italy. It's a combination of acetaminophen (paracetamol) and [sobrelol](https://www.drugs.com/international/sobrerol.html), which is a mucolytic. Basically, it's a cold remedy. It is manufactured by [Sanofi](https://www.sanofi.com/).